# Is it possible to have a cell that has a formula and accepts entry at same time in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

Example:

```
         A          B
1   =vlookup(XX)
2
3
```

in cell A1 there is a Vlookup formula, Is it possible to enable user entry in this cell and override the formula then later restore the formula automatically when sheet is open again?
Even through VBA

Comment: What do you mean "when the sheet is open again"?  Do you mean after the workbook is saved, closed, and re-opened or after the worksheet is re-activated (i.e. you select a different sheet then return).

Comment: Ctrl-Z always works for me :)      But, seriously, there are a number of methods to overwrite, rewrite, prevent from saving, etc.  You need to revise your question to include more about your circumstances and then ask "What is the 'best' way to do this?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short, boring answer: nope.

A cell only ever has a keyed-in *value*, or a calculated *formula*. Can't have both.

---

#### Longer answer: maybe.

Shift everything 1 row down, and use row 1 to store your "original" formula - then hide that row (and pray the user isn't going to mess with it).

*When the sheet is opened again* sounds like you're confusing "workbook" and "worksheet" - you need to handle `Workbook_Open` if you want to run code when a *workbook* opens. Workbooks *contain* worksheets - it's the workbook that opens, not the sheets (sheets *activate*, but I doubt you would want to put that logic in there).

So, in the handler for `Workbook_Open`, write code that takes the formula in the hidden row and overwrites whatever is under it.

Another solution can be to hard-code the formula in the VBA code.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to store your Workbook as a *template*. Normally when a user opens the workbook by double-clicking, it will open whole new workbook based on the template, and they can modify it to their heart's content, save it, mail it to Grandma, etc.

The next person who comes along will double-click the template file and get the formula again, just as you designed it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Kind of, sort of

Long answer:
Save your workbook as a template. Every time someone will use it you'll see the orignal with formula, then if someone write over the formula, when using save your original will be kept intact.

Answer (score 0):

What You need to do is:

press Alt + F11

select ThisWorkbook and paste this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A11").Value = "asdf"

End Sub
```

Every time the workbook is opened, this script will run.

Instead of "Sheet1" you can write the name of the sheet you want to apply the script.

Inside the `Range`, You can define the cells you want to modify, You can use even multiple cells. Check [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/range-object.html) for more information about this.

After `Value` You can write what You want to be written inside the cell. You can write "=vlookup(XX)" and it will work.